# Solving a 2nd Order ODE, then making plots. Size of array returned does not match what I need

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

sorry to bother but I am stuck on a Uni question on 2nd Order ODEs.

I have:

```
def function(init, time, k):
    xt = init[0]
    yt = init[1]
    dotxt = init[2]
    dotyt = init[3]
    dxdt = xt + 2*init[3]
    dydt = yt - 2*init[2]
    return np.array([xt, dotxt, dxdt, yt, dotyt, dydt])

init = [xt, yt, dxdt, dydt] #(but the initial conditions, so 0, 0.2, bla, bla.)
time = np.linspace(0, 10, 500)
k = 0.2131

ans = odeint(function, init, time, args=(k, ))
plt.plot(time, ans[0])
```

I've been given many tasks, but the first that I'm stuck on is producing a graph of time against x values.

I get the obvious error that I have different sizes of arrays, so what can I do, I really am just stuck.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Whenever you report a Python error, include the *complete* error message (i.e. the complete traceback).  There is useful information in there, including the line that triggered the error.  Don't make your readers *guess* where the error is occurring.  Also, it would be easier to help you if you provided a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: In the meantime, look more closely at `ans`.  In particular, note the value of  `ans.shape`.  Is it what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

`scipy.integrate.odeint` expects that `init` matches the dimension of the returned object.  [(see example)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) . Consider the code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
def function(init, time, k):
    xt = init[0]
    yt = init[1]
    dotxt = init[2]
    dotyt = init[3]
    dxdt = xt + 2*init[3]
    dydt = yt - 2*init[2]
    return np.array([xt, dotxt, dxdt, yt, dotyt, dydt])

init = [0, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0] # you need 6 elements, so [0, 0.2, bla, bla, bla, bla]
time = np.linspace(0, 10, 500)
k = 0.2131

ans = odeint(function, init, time, args=(k, ))
plt.plot(time, ans[:, 0])
plt.plot(time, ans[:, 1])
plt.plot(time, ans[:, 2])
plt.plot(time, ans[:, 3])
plt.plot(time, ans[:, 4])
plt.plot(time, ans[:, 5])
```

Which will plot each of the 6 columns against the time array. This may not be exactly correct to what you are trying to do (the ODE function may need to be changed), but it fixes the problem you asked about. The plotting is for demonstration,

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I believe I was just stuck on putting the colon and then comma (plt.plot(time, ans[:, 0])), something so simple. Haha. Cheers.

Comment: @XHB No problem, be sure to hit the check mark next to my answer if it properly answered your question. Thanks